# Elasticsearch - unique facet aggregation in complex products

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

Inspired by the [article](http://project-a.github.io/on-site-search-design-patterns-for-e-commerce/#generic-faceted-search) I'm trying to make a filter for e-commerce with complex product data structure.(Product may have many skus(articles) with there own features)
Hire is a mapping

```
"mappings": {
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      "category_ids": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "create_datetime": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "skus": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "price" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "options": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "feature_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "feature_value_id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a product

```
{
  "name": "some product name",
  "create_datetime": 1493899329,
  "category_ids": [
    851
  ],
  "skus": [
    {
      "price": 885,
      "count": 18,
      "options": [
        {
          "feature_id": "2",
          "feature_value_id": "90"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "3",
          "feature_value_id": "102"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "8",
          "feature_value_id": "596"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "17",
          "feature_value_id": "23"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "23",
          "feature_value_id": "900"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "16",
          "feature_value_id": "368"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "18",
          "feature_value_id": "773"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "price": 1006,
      "count": 0,
      "options": [
        {
          "feature_id": "2",
          "feature_value_id": "90"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "3",
          "feature_value_id": "102"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "8",
          "feature_value_id": "596"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "17",
          "feature_value_id": "23"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "23",
          "feature_value_id": "900"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "16",
          "feature_value_id": "369"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is an aggregation

```
"aggs": {
  "agg_facets": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skus.options"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "feature_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "skus.options.feature_id"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "feature_value_id": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "skus.options.feature_value_id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see product consists of few skus(Stock Keeping Units, and actually they are instances of products, that grouped into product pages(products)).
For example 2 skus are identical , (have same color, material, manufacturer but different size) In this case product consists of 2 skus with given features.
Actually current approach is identical to magento's.  [example of a product](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/mona-pullover-hoodlie.html).

It common that 2 different skus have almost identical features but with few differences.
And given above aggregation calculates number of features in skus.

For example we have 3 products with brand "A" and every product have 3 skus with same brand, but with different sizes. In this case sizes will be calculated correctly, but brand "A" will be aggregated 9 times, but we need 3(without duplicates for a product).

Is there some way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Please, reformulate.

Comment: Done. Hope it is more understandable. Thanks.